# In SASS, how to refer to parent?

Tags: sass

if the hierarchy is as follows:

```
.all
  .d1
    .d2
```

And I want to select ".all" through ".d2". How would it be? Example:

```
.all
  .d1
    .d2
      &:hover
        & .all
          ...
```

The line "& .all" to compile .all ... ???

Comment: You can't, and it doesn't really make sense to want to do so. There is no equivalent CSS for this to compile to.

Comment: Do you want to select every element inside `.all`, or do you want to select `.all:hover`? Can you provide the CSS you're expecting?

Comment: I want to change the div ".all".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply define desired styles under .all:

```
.all
  background: #000 center center no-repeat
  margin: 0 auto
  .dl
    background: #fff center center no-repeat
    margin: 15px
    &:hover
      margin: 0
      text-decoration: none
```

This will output as

```
.all {
  background: #000 center center no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.all .d1 {
  background: #fff center center no-repeat;
  margin: 15px;
}
.all .d1:hover {
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**EDIT**

I didn't understand your question at first.  The answer is this isn't doable via CSS.  You'll want to use jQuery to accomplish this something like this:

like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/9ntg7/1/

**SASS**

```
   .all
      position: relative
      display: block
      height: 100px
      width: 100px
      z-index: 1
      .dl
        position: absolute
        top: 50%
        left: 50%
        display: block
        height: 50px
        width: 50px
        margin: -25px 0 0 -25px
        z-index: 2
        background: white

    .all1
      background: green

    .all2
      background: red
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".dl").hover(function () {
    $(".all").removeClass(".all1")
    $(".all").addClass("all2");
});
```

Comment: This code would change the ".d1", but did not ".all" in the event ":hover".

Comment: You'd want to say .all:hover

Comment: No, ".d2:hover" modify ".all".

Comment: I believe that would be all:hover d2:hover

Comment: @RafaelLaurindo You need to edit your question to be more clear as to what you are wanting.  Further more I am not 100% what you want is doable through CSS, jQuery may get you more results.  Lastly try my edit see if it helps.

Comment: With js would be well:

$(".d2").mouseover ->
  parent = $(this).closest(".all")
  parent.css
    color: "red"

$(".d2").mouseleave ->
  parent = $(this).closest(".all")
  parent.css
    color: "black"

Comment: Had already resolved well. But I confess that it makes me sad when I have to resort to javascript, although I like him very much. I am doing hacks.

Comment: There is a reason Web Developers are better off knowing javascript, css, and html.  The three work together.  There is nothing wrong with using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to output? In your given example you will get a selector like this:

```
.all .d1 .d2.all:hover
```

...if I know SASS (I use LESS).

Is that what you want, or what do you want in the end?

Comment: I want to change the div ".all".

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do something to `<div class="all">`, then you can do this, for example:

```
.all
  color: red
```

If you want to change every thing inside `<div class="all">`, then you can do this:

```
.all *
  color: red
```

Finally, if you want to change only the direct children of `<div class="all">`, you can do this:

```
.all > *
  color: red
```

Comment: There would be none of the options. I would like to change the div ". all" that is father ".d1" and this ".d2", through the event ":hover" on the div ".d2".